# Recovering Data from a Formatted Hard Disk

Tags: linux, windows, data-recovery, formatting

The power adapter of my laptop was not fitting well. Thus, I gave my computer to the repair service for changing the power socket. Today, I received it with a freshly installed Windows on my disk (Hitachi 750GB HDD).

When I saw it was formatted I turned off the computer to avoid writing anything else on the disk. And I bought a SATA to USB3 converter to connect the disk to another computer.

The partition table was changed and a lot of data has been written on the disk. I know it's not possible to get everything back. My aim is to recover as many files as possible.

Firstly, is it possible to revert to the previous disk partitioning?

And, how can I recover my files from this disk?

Comment: “I didn't write anything else on the disk.” - Repair service wrote significant amounts of data.  Questions seeking software recommendations are specifically not within scope.  Use the file recovery software of your choice they are all built equally

Comment: Did the repair company warn you that they might need to wipe the disk? I'm not sure what you mean by "changing the power socket" but it doesn't sound like the kind of thing that would require reinstalling the OS.

Comment: @JamesP, the power adapter was not touching well. All they needed to do was removing the old socket and soldering a new one. For sure, it was nothing related to the OS.

Comment: Send the disk to a professional data recovery service, and the bill to this "repair" shop.

Comment: I'm downvoting this because this question has been answered too many times before.   Google (or search Superuser) from photorec.

Answer (score -1):

By default policy according law, repair companies must notify customers about
the data storage may formatted by security reasons. In most cases, this is only
a small-letter-text on the end of page. Also in most case its not only a 
format, its a wipe (data overwritten with random data before format).

You can use many data revival tools like "Runtime GetDataBack" or "Recuva", but
once the sector overwritten, these tools are worth nothing. If you are lucky,
and only a quick format performed, only the current used size is lost, you can
recover files from the "free space".

There's data backup companies, their price higher than the diamond, in
many case they can recover files once its overwritten (its possible to 
disassembly the drive, and with special heads read the magnetic difference),
but not worth it (dollars per kbytes, nice sum at a 750GB HDD).